# JSF + Trinindad using <tr:inputText> component using required attribute

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I'm using trinidad library,
when the required attribute is set on tr:inputText component from the backing bean, the component shifts to the right.This causes the component to be out of alignment with other components enclosed within a panel box container.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Maybe you can show your JSF page. Without a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) the problem is hard to see ;-)

Comment: Can you add some xhtml of jpsx and maybe an image of the resulting page?

Comment: The Result is that their are 2 inputText components one with an Asterisk (visual indication of required user input) and one with out.

The one with the asterisk is shifted few pixels for the left.

Comment: xhtml page:

<trh:tableLayout>
  <trh:rowLayout>
   <trh:cellFormat>
    <tr:iterator value="#{managedBean.prms}" var="prm"
     <trh:tableLayout layout="horizontal" styleClass="myStyle" >
      <trh:rowLayout>
       <trh:cellFormat>
        <tr:inputText showRequired="#{required}" 
         styleClass="inputStyle" value="#{val}" >
        </tr:inputText>      
       </trh:cellFormat>
      </trh:rowLayout>
     </trh:tableLayout >
    </tr:iterator>
   </trh:cellFormat>  
  </trh:rowLayout>
</trh:tableLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it using CSS. If I am correct the `<tr:inputText/>` is rendered as a table with your `styleClass` set to `inputStyle`. Then the required indicator will be present in the first cell of the first row (even is the input is not required). So you can try something like:

```
.inputStyle tr:first-child td:first-child {
  width: 20px;
}
```